# c++ vector push_back access violation

Tags: c++, exception, stl

I'm struggling with a random exception when using std::vector.

Here are the main elements :

```
struct Stroke
{
    std::vector<vec2>   points;
    Pixel color;
    std::vector<unsigned int> pixelIds;
};

void myFunc()
{
    while (strokes.size() < 5000)
    {
        if (/*A condition that is always met at some point*/)
        {
            break;
        }
        //Some code
        newStroke->pixelIds.clear();
        newStroke->pixelIds.resize(0);
        strokes.push_back(newStroke);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < strokes.size(); ++i)
    {
        drawStroke(strokes[i]);
    }
}



void drawStroke(Stroke * currentStroke)
{
    std::vector<int> roundIds;

    //Fill roundIds

    //Some loops and conditions
    for (int i = 0; i < roundIds.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (/*Check condition*/)
        {
            // Exception is raised deeper in the stack here
            currentStroke->pixelIds.push_back(currentRoundId);
        }
    }
}
```

I left out big parts of the code that shouldn't really affect this because I have no idea where the problem could come from (so I'd have to copy/paste the whole code :D). In the last line I randomly get an Access violation deeper in the stack (_Orphan_Range method of std::vector).

I don't see anything wrong with currentStroke in the watch, the points vector is looking normal, color too, I guess that some internal values of pixelIds are broken (_Myfirst=0x000000000038c700  _MyEnd=0x000000000038c74c doesn't look too good to me but I'm not sure).

I'm not very experienced with the details of STL and I don't know what to look for especially since the vector is only holding unsigned int values, not some fancy weird class or structure and I have no idea what could ever mess up with the internal values of a vector.

Any suggestion or advice will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: this `while(true)` part kills everything

Comment: Standard debugging technique: remove the parts that shouldn't affect the problem, and then _run the code left over_ to see if you still have the problem. If you don't have a problem, you've broken out of your misconceptions. If you still have a problem, then remove parts that you think _might_ be the problem until you don't have a problem anymore. When the problem goes away, you have a very good idea exactly where the issue lies.

Comment: @davidhigh : I guess I left out too many parts of the actual code. I have a condition to break that loop and I make sure that it's hit everytime. (We could argue about poor design but the problem is not linked to this loop being infinite.)

Comment: What makes you think the exception is "random"? Take some personal responsibility!

Comment: @Hurkyl : I agree and already did that but I can't seem to figure out which part is a problem. It's part of a bigger algorithm in which taking a small part out implies taking a big part out just to compile and the same algorithm with different parameters (typically implying less strokes) works just fine, so I can't narrow it down to a specific part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Random doesn't mean it's not my fault. It's my own project running on my machine so it IS my fault. Doesn't mean it's not random.

Comment: @Xelareip: It is most assuredly not "random". :)

Comment: "`if (/*A condition that is always met at some point*/)`" Not good enough. How are we to know that you got that right? Especially when we already know you got something wrong :P **Post a *testcase*.** http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : The problem is probably not random, the exception can be (depending on the layout of your memory, misuse of uninitialized variables, etc...). I'd say it depends on everything that is happening on your machine so it can be considered random.
Don't you agree? :)

Comment: No it can't. You can *always* create an sscce. It might take you a while, but you can always do it. In fact, in creating the sscce, you'll more than likely find, and therefore fix, your problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Fair enough, this while (true) seems to bother everybody, I'll post a different test case

Comment: If `push_back` causes an exception, it's usually because the vector itself is broken. One factor that you haven't shown is how the `Stroke`s are created.

Comment: @Xelareip: I think we have different definitions of "random", but I do understand what you're getting at. At a certain level of abstraction you could probably say it seems random, even though in principle there is never anything truly random about it: there is _always_ a specific cause, even if it's buried deep within layers of implementation that you don't care about. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Well, I'd say the randomness has to be defined in relation with the scale you're looking at. We're talking about a program running on a machine. Run it on the same machine being at the exact same state (Same layout in memory, same hardware, etc... Impossible to recreate in a typical workspace environment) and there's nothing random anymore. Since it's in relation with the rest of the machine (ie : shared memory space) and we have no idea of the state of the rest of the machine, I'd say we can call it random :) (We're getting lost in semantic questions :D )

Comment: It looks like you are passing null or invalid `currentStroke` to `drawStroke`. Show the code where it's created instead of `//Some code` comment.

Answer (score 4):

myFunct has an endless loop that fills stoke vector until you get out of memory.

Comment: I guess I left out too many parts of the actual code. I have a condition to break that loop and I make sure that it's hit everytime. As far as I know my memory is fine (The process only uses a few Mb of RAM). I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: @Xelareip: Then post your _testcase_ that reproduces the issue. There's nothing we can do with some arbitrary _other_ piece of code that bears no useful relationship to the one you're asking about.